# Mercenaries identified by missing appendage (like pinky finger)

Tags: story-identification

earlier to 1975 Military Science Fiction novel I started reading beginning of college and only got through the first few pages. Military men (including aliens) are identified by having a digit (or similar appendage) removed from the end of the hand (like the pinky for humans). The scene compared the reaction time with the mercenaries (quicker) than the galactic police in getting their shields or missile defense up in time.